# Bootstrap 4 Navbar Menus Enclosed By Borders

Tags: html, css, sass, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I am new in bootstrap 4 and I want to know if there is an option in bootstrap 4 for navbar menus enclosed by borders like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYLVa.png)

Thanks!

Comment: share you code, what you have tried ?

Comment: Did you look at the [docs](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/)?

Comment: All I have is the default bootstrap html syntax @MadanBhandari.

Comment: Yep. All the docs offer is the navbar with items equal spacing. @Skelly

Comment: I guess that answers your question. No there is not an option,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.nav-item {
 border-right: 1px solid silver;
 padding-right: 15px; 
}   
.nav-item:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid silver;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color:#fff">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```